# Vim-LaTeX not compiling multiple times

Tags: bibtex, vim-latex

I am not sure why, but when I am working on a multi-file project in `TeX` with a `latexmain` file, the compiler included with `VIM-LaTeX` does not compile multiple times to include newly added citations in my bibliography. This only occurs for multi-file projects. If I work on a project that has only one `TeX` file the file is compiled multiple times to include new citations.

Does anyone have any clue what may be causing this?